# Querying by post type - nothing shown

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I'm trying to display posts of custom post type, but it displays nothing.

I have setup all the custom fields with CPT UI/ACF and everything seems to be smooth until it comes to the display part.

This is the `blog.php` template that I have created:

```
<?php
/**
 * Template Name: Blog template
 *
 * @package Hestia
 * @since Hestia 1.0
 */

get_header();
?>

<?php

$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'blog',
    'posts_per_page' => 10 );
    $loop = new WP_Query( $args );
?>


<?php while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); ?>

    <h1><?php the_field('main_title');?><h1>
    <img src="<?php the_field('header_image');?>" alt="" />
    <p><?php the_field('paragraph_1');?></p>
    <img src="<?php the_field('image_1');?>" alt="" />
    <p><?php the_field('paragraph_2');?><h1>
    <img src="<?php the_field('image_2');?>" alt="" />
    <p><?php the_field('paragraph_3');?><h1>
    <img src="<?php the_field('image_3');?>" alt="" />



<?php endwhile; ?>

    <?php get_footer(); ?>
```

---

```
function cptui_register_my_cpts_blog() {

    /**
     * Post Type: Blog.
     */

    $labels = array(
        "name" => __( "Blog", "hestia-pro" ),
        "singular_name" => __( "blog", "hestia-pro" ),
        "menu_name" => __( "Blog", "hestia-pro" ),
        "all_items" => __( "All posts", "hestia-pro" ),
        "add_new" => __( "Add new", "hestia-pro" ),
        "add_new_item" => __( "Add new post", "hestia-pro" ),
    );

    $args = array(
        "label" => __( "Blog", "hestia-pro" ),
        "labels" => $labels,
        "description" => "",
        "public" => true,
        "publicly_queryable" => true,
        "show_ui" => true,
        "show_in_rest" => false,
        "rest_base" => "",
        "has_archive" => false,
        "show_in_menu" => true,
        "exclude_from_search" => false,
        "capability_type" => "post",
        "map_meta_cap" => true,
        "hierarchical" => false,
        "rewrite" => array( "slug" => "blog", "with_front" => true ),
        "query_var" => true,
        "menu_icon" => "dashicons-welcome-write-blog",
        "supports" => array( "title", "editor", "thumbnail" ),
    );

    register_post_type( "blog", $args );
}

add_action( 'init', 'cptui_register_my_cpts_blog' );
```

The `'post_type'` is correct and same goes for the field names. They all match the custom fields, but for some reason, nothing is displayed.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Set has_archive to true. Had the same problem and this fixed it.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but sadly, that didn't solve it :/

Comment: Are you sure you have data? Can you enter (your url)/blog and get data?